# How should I write a simple *.cir file in LTspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, ltspice

I want to build a schematic block with four pins as follow in LTspice:
pins: Vin,out,Vres,nbit

```
function:
if abs(Vin)>=Vref
Vin=1
end
Vres=Vref/(2^nbit)
out=int(Vin/Vres)
```

Thanks

Comment: And your question is? Because I hope you're not just fishing for a sucker to do it for you.

Comment: you can see my question above! I don't know how I should write spice model.

Comment: You should read the manual, first. Even if it is rather sparse, you will find the information you need there, right in the beginning. For your particular case, you can either use a behavioural source with an `if()` conditional (see `behavioural sources`), or an `A-device` (see` A-devices`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a B-source, you can set the voltage equal to an if-then statement or other math statments. You can find a complete [reference here](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=B_sources_(complete_reference)). This one compares the voltage value of Vin and if its greater than the current of Vg it sets Vref to 1 otherwise Vref is 1

[image]

Here is the netlist output of the b-source (view->netlist):

```
B2 Vref 0 V=IF( V(Vin)>I(Vq),1,V(Vin))
```

Comment: I really appreciate you for your reply. :) it's unique. (I couldn't upvote for you bcoz of my low reputation)